# Require Node.js dependencies in Ruby/Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems, npm, batman.js

I'm having a great time live-reloading JS  with [fb-flo](https://github.com/facebook/fb-flo) in my Rails & [batman.js](http://batmanjs.org) project. I want to move my code into a Ruby gem, but I don't know what to do.

To run the `flo` server, I'll need to `require("fb-flo")`. If this was a node module, I'd just make sure to put my dependencies in package.json. But how can I require `fb-flo` (and its dependencies) in a Ruby gem?

Or, should I just install the dependencies and include them in the gem's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem to make RoR and NodeJS work together :D

https://github.com/Shopify/schmooze